# MVC dropdownlistfor multiple selection not working just open the complete list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

```
public class RollClass
    {
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        public List<RollClass> GetRoleList { get; set; }
    }
```

In controller,

```
 RollClass rc = new RollClass();
            rc.GetRoleList = db.Roles.Select(c => new RollClass {
                RoleID = c.RoleID,
                RoleName = c.RoleName
            }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Roles = rc.GetRoleList;
```

my View bind with user model so i am passing dropdown value through viewbag.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleID, ViewBag.Roles as SelectList,
            "Select Role", new { @class = "form-control", multiple =true })
```

After using multiple=true it is showing me dropdown open means its is showing all three dropdown values and multi selection is not working.

i am using MVC 5 and bootstrap 4.0

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: this might help https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/265/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlists-multiple-selection-and-enum-support

Comment: i already checked this link it did not work

Answer (score 0):

use select2

see these links :

https://select2.org/

and for multi dropdown :

https://select2.org/selections

i used like below :

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleID,ViewBag.Roles as SelectList, new { @class = 
   "select2_tagged form-control", placeholder = "select ..." })


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Select2/js/select2.js"></script>
  <script>
     $("#RoleID").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
            var element = evt.params.data.element;
            var $element = $(element);
            $element.detach();
            $(this).append($element);
            $(this).trigger("change");
        });
  </script>
```